# Different size for the cells

Tags: java, android, xml, android-layout, android-studio

I am making an application everything was fine until I worked on 5 -inch screen. But when I wanted to check how the application looks at the screen 3 inch. It was all terribly enlarged. I wish everything was the same on both screens. I can do that the system will automatically detect the size of the device and have it perform ? Please help.

Comment: Refer this link [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15737659/best-practice-for-multiple-screens-android/15737707#15737707](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15737659/best-practice-for-multiple-screens-android/15737707#15737707).You must create the layout design for different screen sizes.Official documents for different screen support [http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html)

Comment: It is a good practice to provide more layouts for different screens as well as referencing dimensions form resources. You can preview your layout behavior on different screens in android studio.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You Layout folder should be like this.

```
res/layout/my_layout.xml             // layout for normal screen size ("default")
res/layout-small/my_layout.xml       // layout for small screen size
res/layout-large/my_layout.xml       // layout for large screen size
res/layout-xlarge/my_layout.xml      // layout for extra large screen size
res/layout-xlarge-land/my_layout.xml // layout for extra large in landscape orientation
```

In Manifest add support-screens

```
<supports-screens android:resizeable=["true"| "false"]
              android:smallScreens=["true" | "false"]
              android:normalScreens=["true" | "false"]
              android:largeScreens=["true" | "false"]
              android:xlargeScreens=["true" | "false"]
              android:anyDensity=["true" | "false"]
              android:requiresSmallestWidthDp="integer"
              android:compatibleWidthLimitDp="integer"
              android:largestWidthLimitDp="integer"/>
```

For more info check this [Link](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html)

Comment: I have a question Where do I put ten code ? You must be a system folder: (res/layout/my_layout.xml)? What is stated above ?

Comment: All layout design should be in all layout folder .for example if you create splashscreen.xml.this should be in all those folder.

Comment: Fixed. I used a different solution. I changed the font size from px to dp.

Comment: @snaperdak don't use **dp** for font. It's not advisable. Use **sp** for font. Refer the developer website, were to use **dp,sp,px**